# How to use mutate filter plugin in output

Tags: logstash

I have a logstash configuration. With that configuration logstash do some operation in filter and send outputs. Everything works well.

I want one more elasticsearch output in same configuration file. I mean after parsing the logs, logstash
send results to one index after that removing some fields and send them to another index.  My aim is in below example.

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
      ..index1..
 }
 mutate {
   remove_field ...
} 
mutate {
   add_field ..
}
elasticsearch {
  ... index2 ...
}
```

}

But i can not work with mutate plugin in output ? How can i achieve this ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mutate` is a `filter` plugin, so it will only work inside the `filter` block.

What you can do maybe is use the `clone` filter to duplicate your event, apply different filters to the original and cloned event and then deliver the two copies to different outputs accordingly.

It could look roughly like this

```
filter {
  clone {
    clones => ["cloned"]
  }
  # apply here filters that should be applied to both the primary and secondary event
  if [type] == "cloned" {
    # apply here filters that should be applied to the secondary event
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "cloned" {
    elasticsearch {
      ... index2 ...
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      ... index1 ...
    }
  }
}
```

See https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-filter-the-output-data-separately/36064/5

Comment: I m using type multiple times in my filter. How can i use my type and clone together?

Comment: the rules that need to be applied to both variations of the event stay unchanged.
You need the "if [type]" only to apply rules to the second variation. So potentially you can use type mostly as you were using it earlier with the exception of the `output` section

Comment: so ı should copy nearly all of my codes, and remove types in if [type] = cloned and stay original in else block ? You mean this am i understand correctly ?

Comment: I updated the example to make it more clear, does it make more sense now?